# EXC_BAD_ACCESS while doing NSDictionary objectForKey - but the object is there

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsdictionary, lldb

Im getting a rather baffling error when trying to get an object from an `NSDictionary`.  I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when calling `objectForKey`.  When I look at the given objects, everything is fine.  The dictionary exists.  It contains the key I am looking for.  The key is also there.  Everything is totally fine.  So why does `objectForKey` crash on this occasion?  Ive taken a screenshot of both the code and of the console - you can see the properties in question in the print out.  The key is there, and the dictionary contains that key.  But its as though the dictionary doesnt exist or something?  Baffled.  By the way I 'copy'd the dictionary in an attempt to fix the crash, I wouldnt normally do that.

[image: Screenshot of Xcode with crash]

Comment: `self.downloadProgress` property is an `NSDictionary`, ok. What is the property ownership attribute? I guess it is not `copy`, right?

Comment: Look closely to log - you have an `__NSDictionaryM` - which is `mutable` instance. Pretty unexpected right? So check where it becomes mutable and fix it.

Comment: To fix it just add `copy` attribute like this: `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *downloadProgress;` Hope it will help.

Comment: It's probably worth finding out exactly what is causing the segfault. Try using the `p` command (instead of `po`) on some things and finding which thing prints out the same address as shown in the error message.

Comment: Also, are you using automatic reference counting? If not you should.

Comment: Split the statement in smaller pieces (or show disassembly and try to make sense of it). Probably something is released: `self`, `downloadProgress`, `update` or `uniqueId`. Is everything in the same thread?

Comment: Thanks all for comments.  It is defined as an NSMutableDictionary with strong, nonatomic.  Not heard of p command, will try that thanks.  Yes using ARC.  Im pretty sure nothing is released.  It could be threading - checking that.  The project wasnt written by me, though this code is.  I see lots of use of @synchronised - this might be related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here was todo with threading.  As I was correctly reminded in comments, NSMutableDictionary is not thread safe.  It was being updated on a background thread, and the code above was being called on the main thread.  The simplest solution was to wrap these calls in @synchronised. Thanks to all those who chipped in to help.

```
if ([update uniqueId]) {
    @synchronized (self.downloadProgress) {
        if ([self.downloadProgress objectForKey:[update uniqueId]]) {
            NSDictionary *progressInfo = [[self.downloadProgress objectForKey:[update uniqueId]] copy];
            if ([progressInfo objectForKey:@"progressString"]) {
                return [progressInfo objectForKey:@"progressString"];
            } 
        }
    }
} (
```